# Retrieve argument pass to constructor

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

i'm brand new in solidity. I've deployed my first little contract ERC20 with truffle.
With the web3 package on python, i've explored the transaction of this creation, and i was seeking of the arguments i passed to the constructor (name, initialsupply ...), but i can't find them.
Is there a way to find this argument in the blockchain ? Are they hide in the hash of the input ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor arguments are encoded at the end of the deployed bytecode.

---

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    constructor(uint256 _foo) {
    }
}
```

Compiled bytecode:

```
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060405160dc38038060dc8339818101604052810190
602d91906045565b506090565b600081519050603f81607c565b92915050565b60006020828403
121560585760576077565b5b60006064848285016032565b91505092915050565b600081905091
9050565b600080fd5b608381606d565b8114608d57600080fd5b50565b603f80609d6000396000
f3fe6080604052600080fdfea264697066735822122003a184614c306711c11c8169439e473b01
fb186c8094644efc80975e3fe2660964736f6c63430008060033
```

Deployed bytecode:

```
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060405160dc38038060dc8339818101604052810190
602d91906045565b506090565b600081519050603f81607c565b92915050565b60006020828403
121560585760576077565b5b60006064848285016032565b91505092915050565b600081905091
9050565b600080fd5b608381606d565b8114608d57600080fd5b50565b603f80609d6000396000
f3fe6080604052600080fdfea264697066735822122003a184614c306711c11c8169439e473b01
fb186c8094644efc80975e3fe2660964736f6c63430008060033
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e240
```

Where the `1e240` is hex value of decimal `123456`. The length of 64 hex characters (including the leading zeros) is because of the length of the 256 bit (64 hex chars) `uint` datatype.